# Ubuntu in virtual machine can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu-15.04, vmware-player

First I must say that I have no idea what kind of problem it is (Ubuntu/Windows/vmware/secureW2), so I hope anyone can select the necessary information from this mess.

I am running an Ubuntu 15.04 guest on a Windows 10 host using the vmware Virtual Machine. The Ubuntu internet icon in the right hand corner claims that it has a (wired) connection, yet I can't browse or ping google. Windows 10 is successfully connected by wi-fi, vmware uses a bridged connection (automatic) and my router enables DHCP. I can successfully ping my router from within the VM (at least, I assume 192.168.1.1 still refers to my actual router, and not some virtual router). In windows I can see two network adapters running (VMnet1 and VMnet8), both of which say they're enabled but have no internet access. I tried installing the bridge protocol in them, I tried using NAT instead of a bridge, but all to no avail. I was still connected just a few days ago when I was at school, which makes me think SecureW2 (a program responsible for connecting me to the school wi-fi) could also be involved somehow.

Everyone thanks in advance!

Comment: I just managed to ping google using its IP, which makes me think a DNS problem could also be possible. Or does the Ubuntu terminal simply not support domain name pings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was DNS related, caused by Ubuntu and SecureW2. The `/etc/resolv.conf` file was set up specifically for the LAN at school, for which I blame SecureW2. I "solved" it by adding my router IP to (the top of) the name server list, though I know this is only a practical solution.